# Add bibliography to toc with KOMA-Script

Tags: biblatex, koma-script, documentclass-writing

I try to write a small class for myself at the moment. So far everything is working as expected except of putting the bibliography title inside the table of content. Normally I use the KOMA option `bibliography=totoc` and `listof=totoc` and everything is working fine.

What I've done is to create a class which accept three options:

- add-tocs-to-toc  (List of figure, list of tables, literatur)
- add-bibliography (Loads biblatex and csquotes)
- bib-file (pass custom bib file)

The KOMA option `listof=totoc` is working as aspected.

My class file bibtest.cls

```
\ProvidesClass{bib-test}[2017-11-12 v0.1 MWE]

\RequirePackage{etoolbox, pgfopts, scrlfile}

\newcommand*{\bibtest@cls@baseclass}{scrreprt}
\newcommand*{\bibtest@cls@baseclass@options}{}

% ----------------------------------------------------------
% Define booleans
% ----------------------------------------------------------
\newbool{bibtest@cls@if@bib}
\newbool{bibtest@cls@if@tocstotoc}

% ----------------------------------------------------------
% Define available options
% ----------------------------------------------------------
\pgfkeys{
    bibtest/.cd,
        add-tocs-to-toc/.is if      = bibtest@cls@if@tocstotoc,
        add-bibliography/.is if     = bibtest@cls@if@bib,
        bib-file/.store in          = \bibtest@bib@file,
        bib-file = {},
        unknown/.code               = \edef\bibtest@cls@baseclass@options{\bibtest@cls@baseclass@options,\pgfkeyscurrentname}
}

\ifbool{bibtest@cls@if@tocstotoc}{%
    \KOMAoptions{%
        listof  = totoc,
        bibliography = totoc
    }
}{}

\ProcessPgfOptions{/bibtest}

\LoadClass[\bibtest@cls@baseclass@options]{\bibtest@cls@baseclass}

\ifbool{bibtest@cls@if@bib}{%
    \AfterPackage{inputenc}{\RequirePackage[autostyle]{csquotes}}%
    \AtEndDocument{\printbibliography}%
    \RequirePackage[%
        backend      = biber,
        style        = numeric-comp
    ]{biblatex}%
    \ifdefempty{\bibtest@bib@file}{%
        \IfFileExists{source.bib}{%
            \pgfkeys{/bibtest/bib-file = source.bib}%
        }{%
            \ClassWarning{bibtest}{Cannot find default source.bib file.}%
        }%
    }{%
        \IfFileExists{\bibtest@bib@file}{}{%
            \ClassWarning{bibtest}{Couldn't find passed bib file}
        }%
    }%
    \addbibresource{\bibtest@bib@file}%
}{}%

\endinput
```

The MWE for testing

```
\documentclass[
    add-tocs-to-toc,
    add-bibliography,
    bib-file = biblatex-examples.bib
]{bibtest}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \listoffigures
    \listoftables

        \chapter{Hallo Welt}
            Hallo Welt
        \chapter{Hello World}
            Hello World \cite{aksin}
\end{document}
```

As you might see there is no literatur entry inside the table of content. I tested under Windows 10 with MiKTeX.

Comment: There is also no bibliography at all. Why should there be an entry? By the way, not KOMA, but `biblatex` is resposible for the entry.

Comment: You are overcomplicating a simple document for the sake of nothing.  A class should not have a lot of testing and loading of packages.

Comment: The class provides `\AtEndDocument{\printbibliography}` to generate the bibliography, when the option `add-bibliography` is set.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you use `biblatex` together with the KOMA classes it is actually `biblatex` who is responsible for the format of the heading in your `bibliography` and not the KOMA class.

Confer also the warning in the [KOMA documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/doc/scrguien.pdf) (p. 139)

> Using an additional bibliography style like `natbib`, `babelbib`, or `biblatex` limits the influence of KOMA-Script to the bibliography hardly.  In such cases it is important so see the manual of the bibliography package!

Starting from version 3.8 of `biblatex` and version 3.25 of KOMA script, the two packages will work together more closely. KOMA script has added a new command `\bibliography@heading` to typeset the bibliography heading and that command can be used by `biblatex`. The standard `bibliography` and `biblist` headings now use this command with KOMA classes. In essence that means that `biblatex` hands control over the bibliography heading back to KOMA (this behaviour can be overridden explicitly), so the default heading will obey all of KOMA script's options. Thanks to Markus Kohm for making that possible. More details can be found in https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/627 and https://sourceforge.net/p/koma-script/code/2685/tree//trunk/scrkernel-bibliography.dtx?diff=52f0ae7181b24b7fb854e8b2:2684.

There are further ideas to make it easier for document classes to work together with `biblatex`, but that would likely require change in both `biblatex` and the respective classes. If you have any ideas or comments, please share them at https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/693.

---

`biblatex` has some rudimentary code to detect certain class options passed to the KOMA classes. This, however, only works if the option is passed as optional global argument while loading the class. It does not work with `\KOMAoptions`.

The [`biblatex` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf) mentions on p. 130 in footnote 27 (emphasis mine)

> This applies to the traditional syntax of these options (`bibtotoc`
>   and `bibtotocnumbered`) as well as to the `<key>=<value>` syntax introduced in KOMA-Script 3.x, i.e., to `bibliography=nottotoc`, `bibliography=totoc`, and `bibliography=totocnumbered`. The global `toc=bibliography` and `toc=bibliographynumbered` options as well as their aliases
>   are detected as well. **In any case, the options must be set globally in the optional argument to `\documentclass`**.

So you will have to use `biblatex` commands and options to get the bibliography to appear in the TOC, not KOMA options.

Instead of `\printbibliography` use `\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]`.

Alternatively, you can redefine the standard `\defbibheading{bibliography}`. Or you could manually set

```
 \let\ifkomabibtotoc=\@firstoftwo
 \let\ifkomabibtotocnumbered=\@secondoftwo
```

in `bibtest@cls@if@tocstotoc`.

Comment: I wish every answer here on TeX.SX would be so good :-)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. `\printbibliography[heading=bibtotoc]`give me the error "! Package biblatex Error: Heading 'bibtotoc' not found."
If I use global options as suggested in the documentation the bibliography entry within the TOC is generated.

Comment: @faltfe Ooop, sorry. It should have been `heading=bibintoc`. Corrected.

Comment: @moewe Thanks, now it is working as aspected.