# How to add chapter/section number to bibliography? "Numbib" from tocbibind doesn't work!

Tags: biblatex, tocbibind

I want my bibliography to appear as a chapter with a page number on its page as well as in the TOC. I tried including `\usepackage[numbib]{tocbibind}` but that  doesn't work for me. Here is a simple example:

```
\documentclass[]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[nottoc, numbib]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\bibliography{sources.bib}

\title{Testdokument}

\begin{document}
    \maketitle

    \tableofcontents

    \section{Erstes Kapitel}
    \lipsum
    \cite{Bib1}

    \clearpage

    \printbibliography
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\bibname}
\end{document}
```

Source.bib just contains 1 entry for testing:

```
@online
{Bib1,
    url     = {https://www.123.com},
    title   = {Website title},
    urldate = {2018-06-06}
}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use `tocbibind` with KOMA classes like `scrartcl`. From the `.log` file:

> ```
> Class scrartcl Warning: Usage of package `tocbibind' together
> (scrartcl)              with a KOMA-Script class is not recommended.
> (scrartcl)              I'd suggest to use options like `listof=totoc'
> (scrartcl)              or `bibliography=totoc', or commands like
> (scrartcl)              `\setuptoc{toc}{totoc}' instead of this package,
> (scrartcl)              because it breaks several KOMA-Script features of
> (scrartcl)              the list of figures, list of tables, bibliography,
> (scrartcl)              index and the running head.
> ```

Use a class option instead. In this case `bibliography=numbered`.

```
\documentclass[bibliography=numbered]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\bibliography{biblatex-examples.bib}

\title{Testdokument}

\begin{document}
  \maketitle
  \tableofcontents

  \section{Erstes Kapitel}
  \lipsum \cite{sigfridsson}

  \clearpage
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: TOC of the MWE 1 "Erstes Kapitel", 2 "Literatur"]

[image: Last page of the MWE: The bibliography with heading: "2 Literatur"]

The compatibility between KOMA script options and `biblatex`'s headings was improved recently. Earlier versions of `biblatex` could only deal with KOMA options if they were given as global class options (because `biblatex` intercepted the options), newer versions hand control over the bibliography heading over to KOMA script. You can read more about that in [Add bibliography to toc with KOMA-Script](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/400934/35864).

Note that `\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\bibname}` would have been wrong anyway since it writes the last page of the bibliography to the table of contents.

---

If you don't use a KOMA class `tocbibind` still does not do the right thing (it does not produce a warning, though). `tocbibind` does not work together with `biblatex` at all, in that case you should use the optional argument `heading=bibnumbered` to `\printbibliography`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\bibliography{biblatex-examples.bib}

\title{Testdokument}

\begin{document}
  \maketitle
  \tableofcontents

  \section{Erstes Kapitel}
  \lipsum \cite{sigfridsson}

  \clearpage
  \printbibliography[heading=bibnumbered]
\end{document}
```

The optional argument `\printbibliography[heading=bibnumbered]` also works for KOMA classes, but I prefer the class argument in that case (if you decide to switch back from `biblatex` to BibTeX bibliographies, for example).

Comment: But that still doesn't solve the problem with the number.

Comment: @11011100 Please check the edit, I wrote `bibliography=totoc` at first when it should have been `bibliography=numbered`.