# Display bibliography as a numbered chapter in the table of contents with bibLaTeX

Tags: biblatex, chapters, tocbibind

I want to display my bibliography as if it was a chapter, specifically the heading should look like a chapter heading, it should be numbered like a chapter, and the page number should be (chapter number)-(page number), and it should displayed in the TOC like a Chapter.

I have tried the `numbib` command from `tocbibind`, and I have also tried passing `bibliography = numbered` in the document class but it does not seem to make a difference.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,bibliography=numbered,oneside]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage[maxcitenames=2, 
  maxbibnames=99, 
  backend=biber, 
  citestyle=authoryear, 
  bibstyle=authoryear, 
  sorting=nyt, %sort by name title year 
  natbib=true,
  giveninits=true,
  hyperref
  ]{biblatex} % CustomBib

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given} % that multiple authors get shorted familty name-given name
\setlength\bibitemsep{1.5\itemsep}
\bibliography{References/references} % Path to your References.bib file
\usepackage[nottoc,numbib]{tocbibind} % to include in table of content heading in the TOC, to have the bibliograph display as a normal section
\usepackage[auto]{chappg} %want to have page numbering per section, example 1-1,1-2,1-3, 2-1 etc.

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman} 
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\pagenumbering{bychapter}
\chapter{First chapter}
\newpage
\chapter{Second chapter}
blabla bla \citep{2000_adams_prob}
\cleardoublepage
\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc, title={References}]
\end{document}
```

My referances.bib file contains the following entry:

```
@book{2000_adams_prob,
  title={Urban stormwater management planning with analytical probabilistic models},
  author={Adams, Barry J},
  year={2000},
  publisher={John Wiley and Sons, Inc., New York, NY (US)}
}
```

[image]

Comment: Related, for KOMA classes: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/451691/177

Comment: The option `bibliography=numbered,` you are passing to the document class looks like a KOMA-Script option. With the KOMA-Script classes this option alone would be enough (you would not need and should not have `heading=bibintoc,` in that case). But with the `book` class the option is ignored: `LaTeX Warning: Unused global option(s): [bibliography=numbered].`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just change the option `heading` from `bibintoc` to `bibnumbered`:

```
\printbibliography[heading=bibnumbered, title={References}]
```

There's no need for `tocbibind`, by the way.

Adapting your MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,bibliography=numbered,oneside]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage[maxcitenames=2,
  maxbibnames=99,
  backend=biber,
  citestyle=authoryear,
  bibstyle=authoryear,
  sorting=nyt, %sort by name title year
  natbib=true,
  giveninits=true,
  hyperref
  ]{biblatex} % CustomBib


\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{2000_adams_prob,
  title={Urban stormwater management planning with analytical probabilistic models},
  author={Adams, Barry J},
  year={2000},
  publisher={John Wiley and Sons, Inc., New York, NY (US)}
}
\end{filecontents}

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given} % that multiple authors get shorted familty name-given name
\setlength\bibitemsep{1.5\itemsep}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib} % Path to your References.bib file
\usepackage[auto]{chappg} %want to have page numbering per section, example 1-1,1-2,1-3, 2-1 etc.

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\pagenumbering{bychapter}
\chapter{First chapter}
\newpage
\chapter{Second chapter}
blabla bla \citep{2000_adams_prob}
\cleardoublepage
\printbibliography[heading=bibnumbered, title={References}]
\end{document}
```

[image]